# how to put side bar under the video box

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, blogger

my problem with embed playlist
i tried to make my (li) list under the video box but all my attempt failure .so how some one re correct my code  ,here my code

```js
<script src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js' type = 'text/javascript' / >
<script>
//<![CDATA[
/*hoverscroll v.0.2.4*/
(function($) {
 $.fn.hoverscroll = function(params) {
  if (!params) {
   params = {};
  }
  params = $.extend({}, $.fn.hoverscroll.params, params);
  this.each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if (params.debug) {
    $.log('[HoverScroll] Trying to create hoverscroll on element ' + this.tagName + '#' + this.id);
   }
   if (params.fixedArrows) {
    $this.wrap('<div class="fixed-listcontainer"></div>')
   } else {
    $this.wrap('<div class="listcontainer"></div>');
   }

   $this.addClass('list');
   var listctnr = $this.parent();
   listctnr.wrap('<div class="ui-widget-content hoverscroll' +
    (params.rtl && !params.vertical ? " rtl" : "") + '"></div>');
   //listctnr.wrap('<div class="hoverscroll"></div>');

   var ctnr = listctnr.parent();

   var leftArrow, rightArrow, topArrow, bottomArrow;
   if (params.arrows) {
    if (!params.vertical) {
     if (params.fixedArrows) {
      leftArrow = '<div class="fixed-arrow left"></div>';
      rightArrow = '<div class="fixed-arrow right"></div>';

      listctnr.before(leftArrow).after(rightArrow);
     } else {
      leftArrow = '<div class="arrow left"></div>';
      rightArrow = '<div class="arrow right"></div>';

      listctnr.append(leftArrow).append(rightArrow);
     }
    } else {
     if (params.fixedArrows) {
      topArrow = '<div class="fixed-arrow top"></div>';
      bottomArrow = '<div class="fixed-arrow bottom"></div>';

      listctnr.before(topArrow).after(bottomArrow);
     } else {
      topArrow = '<div class="arrow top"></div>';
      bottomArrow = '<div class="arrow bottom"></div>';

      listctnr.append(topArrow).append(bottomArrow);
     }
    }
   }
   ctnr.width(params.width).height(params.height);

   if (params.arrows && params.fixedArrows) {
    if (params.vertical) {
     topArrow = listctnr.prev();
     bottomArrow = listctnr.next();

     listctnr.width(params.width)
      .height(params.height - (topArrow.height() + bottomArrow.height()));
    } else {
     leftArrow = listctnr.prev();
     rightArrow = listctnr.next();

     listctnr.height(params.height)
      .width(params.width - (leftArrow.width() + rightArrow.width()));
    }
   } else {
    listctnr.width(params.width).height(params.height);
   }

   var size = 0;

   if (!params.vertical) {
    ctnr.addClass('horizontal');
    $this.children().each(function() {
     $(this).addClass('item');

     if ($(this).outerWidth) {
      size += $(this).outerWidth(true);
     } else {
      size += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-left')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-right')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-left')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-right'));
     }
    });
    $this.width(size);

    if (params.debug) {
     $.log('[HoverScroll] Computed content width : ' + size + 'px');
    }
    if (ctnr.outerWidth) {
     size = ctnr.outerWidth();
    } else {
     size = ctnr.width() + parseInt(ctnr.css('padding-left')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('padding-right')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('margin-left')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('margin-right'));
    }

    if (params.debug) {
     $.log('[HoverScroll] Computed container width : ' + size + 'px');
    }
   } else {
    ctnr.addClass('vertical');
    $this.children().each(function() {
     $(this).addClass('item')

     if ($(this).outerHeight) {
      size += $(this).outerHeight(true);
     } else {
      size += $(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom')) + parseInt($(this).css('margin-bottom'));
     }
    });
    $this.height(size);

    if (params.debug) {
     $.log('[HoverScroll] Computed content height : ' + size + 'px');
    }
    if (ctnr.outerHeight) {
     size = ctnr.outerHeight();
    } else {
     size = ctnr.height() + parseInt(ctnr.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('padding-bottom')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('margin-top')) + parseInt(ctnr.css('margin-bottom'));
    }

    if (params.debug) {
     $.log('[HoverScroll] Computed container height : ' + size + 'px');
    }
   }
   var zone = {
    1: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0,
     to: 0.06 * size,
     direction: -1,
     speed: 16
    },
    2: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.06 * size,
     to: 0.15 * size,
     direction: -1,
     speed: 8
    },
    3: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.15 * size,
     to: 0.25 * size,
     direction: -1,
     speed: 4
    },
    4: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.25 * size,
     to: 0.4 * size,
     direction: -1,
     speed: 2
    },
    5: {
     action: 'stop',
     from: 0.4 * size,
     to: 0.6 * size
    },
    6: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.6 * size,
     to: 0.75 * size,
     direction: 1,
     speed: 2
    },
    7: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.75 * size,
     to: 0.85 * size,
     direction: 1,
     speed: 4
    },
    8: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.85 * size,
     to: 0.94 * size,
     direction: 1,
     speed: 8
    },
    9: {
     action: 'move',
     from: 0.94 * size,
     to: size,
     direction: 1,
     speed: 16
    }
   }

   ctnr[0].isChanging = false;
   ctnr[0].direction = 0;
   ctnr[0].speed = 1;

   function checkMouse(x, y) {
    x = x - ctnr.offset().left;
    y = y - ctnr.offset().top;

    var pos;
    if (!params.vertical) {
     pos = x;
    } else {
     pos = y;
    }

    for (i in zone) {
     if (pos >= zone[i].from && pos < zone[i].to) {
      if (zone[i].action == 'move') {
       startMoving(zone[i].direction, zone[i].speed);
      } else {
       stopMoving();
      }
     }
    }
   }

   function setArrowOpacity() {
    if (!params.arrows || params.fixedArrows) {
     return;
    }

    var maxScroll;
    var scroll;

    if (!params.vertical) {
     maxScroll = listctnr[0].scrollWidth - listctnr.width();
     scroll = listctnr[0].scrollLeft;
    } else {
     maxScroll = listctnr[0].scrollHeight - listctnr.height();
     scroll = listctnr[0].scrollTop;
    }
    var limit = params.arrowsOpacity;
    var opacity = (scroll / maxScroll) * limit;

    if (opacity > limit) {
     opacity = limit;
    }
    if (isNaN(opacity)) {
     opacity = 0;
    }

    var done = false;
    if (opacity <= 0) {
     $('div.arrow.left, div.arrow.top', ctnr).hide();
     if (maxScroll > 0) {
      $('div.arrow.right, div.arrow.bottom', ctnr).show().css('opacity', limit);
     }
     done = true;
    }
    if (opacity >= limit || maxScroll <= 0) {
     $('div.arrow.right, div.arrow.bottom', ctnr).hide();
     done = true;
    }

    if (!done) {
     $('div.arrow.left, div.arrow.top', ctnr).show().css('opacity', opacity);
     $('div.arrow.right, div.arrow.bottom', ctnr).show().css('opacity', (limit - opacity));
    }
   }

   function startMoving(direction, speed) {
    if (ctnr[0].direction != direction) {
     if (params.debug) {
      $.log('[HoverScroll] Starting to move. direction: ' + direction + ', speed: ' + speed);
     }

     stopMoving();
     ctnr[0].direction = direction;
     ctnr[0].isChanging = true;
     move();
    }
    if (ctnr[0].speed != speed) {
     if (params.debug) {
      $.log('[HoverScroll] Changed speed: ' + speed);
     }

     ctnr[0].speed = speed;
    }
   }

   function stopMoving() {
    if (ctnr[0].isChanging) {
     if (params.debug) {
      $.log('[HoverScroll] Stoped moving');
     }

     ctnr[0].isChanging = false;
     ctnr[0].direction = 0;
     ctnr[0].speed = 1;
     clearTimeout(ctnr[0].timer);
    }
   }

   function move() {
    if (ctnr[0].isChanging == false) {
     return;
    }

    setArrowOpacity();

    var scrollSide;
    if (!params.vertical) {
     scrollSide = 'scrollLeft';
    } else {
     scrollSide = 'scrollTop';
    }

    listctnr[0][scrollSide] += ctnr[0].direction * ctnr[0].speed;
    ctnr[0].timer = setTimeout(function() {
     move();
    }, 50);
   }

   if (params.rtl && !params.vertical) {
    listctnr[0].scrollLeft = listctnr[0].scrollWidth - listctnr.width();
   }

   ctnr
    .mousemove(function(e) {
     checkMouse(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    })
    .bind('mouseleave', function() {
     stopMoving();
    });

   this.startMoving = startMoving;
   this.stopMoving = stopMoving;

   if (params.arrows && !params.fixedArrows) {
    // Initialise arrow opacity
    setArrowOpacity();
   } else {
    // Hide arrows
    $('.arrowleft, .arrowright, .arrowtop, .arrowbottom', ctnr).hide();
   }
  });

  return this;
 };

 if (!$.fn.offset) {
  $.fn.offset = function() {
   this.left = this.top = 0;

   if (this[0] && this[0].offsetParent) {
    var obj = this[0];
    do {
     this.left += obj.offsetLeft;
     this.top += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
   }

   return this;
  }
 }

 $.fn.hoverscroll.params = {
  vertical: false,
  width: 400,
  height: 50,
  arrows: true,
  arrowsOpacity: 0.7,
  fixedArrows: false,
  rtl: false,
  debug: false
 };
 $.log = function() {
  try {
   console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  } catch (e) {
   try {
    opera.postError.apply(opera, arguments);
   } catch (e) {}
  }
 };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
 $("#videoslider-tabs a").click(function() {
  var container = $("#videoslider-content");
  container.html("<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5iLHgsmg5gE/UjhXqejYSNI/AAAAAAAAD2Y/x5jtMwID_X4/s1600/loading.png' class='loading-vid' />");
  var id = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
  loadvideo(id);
  return false;
 });
 $("#videoslider-tabs").hoverscroll({
  vertical: true,
  width: 300,
  height: 330,
  arrows: false
 });
 $("#videoslider-tabs li").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("hover");
 }, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
 });
 loadvideo();
});

function loadvideo(hash) {
  if (hash) {
   hash = hash.slice(3);
   $("#videoslider-content").html(video[hash]);
   $("#videoslider-tabs li").removeClass("actVid");
   $("#videoslider-tabs a[href=#vid" + hash + "]").parent().addClass("actVid");
  } else {
   $("#videoslider-content").html(video[1]);
   $("#videoslider-tabs li").removeClass("actVid");
   $("#videoslider-tabs a[href=#vid1]").parent().addClass("actVid");
  }
 }
 //]]>
</script>
```

```css
<style>
 #videoslider {
 background: #F6F6F6;
 /* Background color */
 
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 735px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
 -moz-background-clip: padding;
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 background-clip: padding-box;
}

#videoslider,
#videoslider-content,
#videoslider-tabs {
 height: 340px;
}

#videoslider-content {
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 width: 430px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.loading-vid {
 display: block;
 margin: 165px auto 0;
}

#videoslider-tabs {
 float: right;
 width: 240px;
 margin: 0;
}

#videoslider-tabs li {
 background-color: #F6F6F6;
 border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
 float: left;
 height: 60px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 240px;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#videoslider-tabs li a {
 padding: 0 !important;
 border: 0 !important;
}

#videoslider-tabs li.hover {
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
}

#videoslider-tabs li.actVid {
 background: #555;
}

#videoslider-tabs li img.thumb-vid {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 float: left;
 height: 52px;
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 52px;
}

#videoslider-tabs li span.vidTit {
 display: block;
 color: #128EC9;
 /* Titles color */
 
 font-size: 12px;
 /* Titles font size */
 
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#videoslider-tabs li .vidDesc {
 display: block;
 color: #222222;
 /* Color of the description */
 
 font-size: 11px;
 /* Font size of the description */
 
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#videoslider-tabs a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#videoslider-tabs li.actVid .vidDesc {
 color: #fff;
}

#videoslider-tabs li span.vidTit .actVid {
 color: #fff;
 /* Titles color */
}

.ui-widget-content {
 float: right;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tabs-outer {
 background-image: none !important;
}

#videoslider-tabs li a:hover {
 background: none !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script>
var video = [];
video[1] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[2] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[3] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[4] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[5] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_5" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
</script>
<div id="videoslider">
<div id="videoslider-content"></div>
<ul id="videoslider-tabs">
<li><a href="#vid1"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_1/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#vid2"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_2/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#vid3"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_3/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#vid4"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_4/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#vid5"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_5/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

so can some one look and re correct my code , because i want to make the list under the video box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yk8j94qm/

Comment: pls can you check the tick mark beside the answer (it appears on hover) if you find my answer useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the list horizontally, then look at the snippet. If you want to display it vertically, but under the video, just close the div before your ul, not after.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#videoslider-tabs a").click(function() {
    var container = $("#videoslider-content");
    container.html("<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5iLHgsmg5gE/UjhXqejYSNI/AAAAAAAAD2Y/x5jtMwID_X4/s1600/loading.png' class='loading-vid' />");
    var id = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
    loadvideo(id);
    return false;
  });
  $("#videoslider-tabs").hoverscroll({
    vertical: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 330,
    arrows: false
  });
  $("#videoslider-tabs li").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  });
  loadvideo();
});

function loadvideo(hash) {
  if (hash) {
    hash = hash.slice(3);
    $("#videoslider-content").html(video[hash]);
    $("#videoslider-tabs li").removeClass("actVid");
    $("#videoslider-tabs a[href=#vid" + hash + "]").parent().addClass("actVid");
  } else {
    $("#videoslider-content").html(video[1]);
    $("#videoslider-tabs li").removeClass("actVid");
    $("#videoslider-tabs a[href=#vid1]").parent().addClass("actVid");
  }
}

var video = [];
video[1] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[2] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[3] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[4] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
video[5] = '<iframe width="460" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_ID_5" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
#videoslider {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  /* Background color */
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 740px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#videoslider,
#videoslider-content,
#videoslider-tabs {
  height: 340px;
}
#videoslider-content {
  color: #fff;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 740px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.loading-vid {
  display: block;
  margin: 145px auto 0;
}
ul#videoslider-tabs {
  width: 740px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 132px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
ul li.hover {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
ul li.actVid {
  background: #555;
}
ul li img.thumb-vid {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  float: left;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 52px;
}
ul li span.vidTit {
  display: block;
  color: #128EC9;
  /* Titles color */
  font-size: 12px;
  /* Titles font size */
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li span.vidDesc {
  display: block;
  color: #222222;
  /* Color of the description */
  font-size: 11px;
  /* Font size of the description */
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li.actVid .vidDesc {
  color: #fff;
}
ul li span.vidTit .actVid {
  color: #fff;
  /* Titles color */
}
.ui-widget-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.tabs-outer {
  background-image: none !important;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background: none !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="videoslider"></div>
  <div id="videoslider-content">

    <ul id="videoslider-tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#vid1">
          <img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_1/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#vid2">
          <img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_2/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span</a></li>

<li><a href="#vid3"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_3/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#vid4">
          <img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_4/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span</a></li>

<li><a href="#vid5"><img src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/video_ID_5/default.jpg" class="thumb-vid" /><span class="vidTit">Video Name</span><span class="vidDesc">Video Description</span</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
    </body>
```